# How to overload a built-in CUDA function?

Tags: cuda, pycuda

CUDA has some built-in math functions, such as norm(). I want to create my own version of the norm() function, and use my version throughout the code. However when I define my own norm() function like so:

```
__device__ float norm(float a, float b) {
    return sqrt(a*a+b*b);
}
```

I get the following compilation error:

```
kernel.cu(9): error: more than one instance of overloaded function "norm" has "C" linkage
```

Is there a way I can overload the norm() function, or do I have to just give my own function a unique name?

I'm using PyCuda to compile my CUDA code.

Comment: Don't use C linkage, obviously

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is the use of C linkage in your code.

You may or may not be explicitly specifying `extern "C"`anywhere. Irrespective of whether you are, if you are using the PyCUDA `SourceModule` facility to compile your code, it is (un)helpfully, automagically bracketing the code you submit with `extern "C"`.

If you look at the [documentation](https://documen.tician.de/pycuda/driver.html#module-pycuda.compiler) for `SourceModule`, you will see the option `no_extern_c`. Set that to `True` and this problem will go away. But note that *everything* you compile will now be compiled with C++ linkage and symbol mangling. You will have to adapt your Python code accordingly (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21405901/681865) for some of the gory details).

And after that, read the other answer, which contains some very sage advice about the perils of overloading standard libraries and a best practice alternative.

Comment: Did you mean that "no_extern_c" needs to be set to True?

Comment: yeah sorry, that was what I meant

Answer (score 1):

I'll make two suggestions in addition to [@talonmies' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44995416/1593077) - in case you do manage to get overloading working:

1. General non-CUDA-specific advice: **Avoid overloading the builtins / API functions of a library**, unless that is absolutely necessary (which it isn't in your case). 
   Reasons for this:

   - Likely to confuse other readers of your code
   - Mixing up "wrapper" code with builtins - it's not a "clean" way to code.
   - If the builtins change, your code using the builtins+overloads is likely to also have to change, sometimes in ways you didn't expect.
2. In your case, I would seriously consider having some namespace with your utility functions, e.g.

   ```
   namespace math {
       template <typename T>  
       __device__ T norm(T a, T b) { return math::sqrt<T>(a*a+b*b); }
   }
   ```

   (of course you would need a `math::sqrt` template, which would abstract from the single-precision `sqrtf()`, double-precision `sqrt()` etc.)

Comment: @talonmies: If he implemented his custom `norm` function within a namespace, he would not get the linking error, since it would not conflict with any C-linkage function. IIANM.

Comment: The problem is PyCUDA compiles everything with C linkage by default. It is why the code is breaking in the first place. You can do what you propose, but the moment you try compiling multiple template instances within the same namespace, you hit the same problem.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by this: "CUDA doesn't have a built-in double-precision square root"   There is [this](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__DOUBLE.html#group__CUDA__MATH__DOUBLE_1g1c6fe34b4ac091e40eceeb0bae58459f) of course.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: Missed it, sorry. I used the search feature for "sqrt", found the mathemtical functions section and didn't look at the double-precision section.